# Manipulating arctan function for height and position of asymptote

Tags: trigonometry, asymptotics

I'm trying to modify an `arctan` function such that it asymptotes to some predefined `y` value at some predefined position along an `x` input array.

Does anyone know how to do this or can point me in the right direction?

So far I have been using:

modified arctan = $\frac{2}{\pi} \text{arctan} \left(\pi x \right)$ ,

To ensure that the function aymptotes to a `y` value of 1.

And I assume that one can manipulate the region at which it approaches 1 by changing:

$\text{arctan} \left(\pi x \right)$ to $\text{arctan} \left(\frac{\pi x}{N} \right)$

Obviously I realise that this function will never actually meet the required `y` value but perhaps there's a way to put a handle on where the curve reaches some predefined gradient... say 1 or $<0.5$ etc.

But where this handle `N` is, I'm not sure and maybe there's a better way to accomplish this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated so thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583677/function-with-two-conditions/3583732#3583732) help?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are fixed, how is that an asymptote?

Comment: @AndrewChin It does, thank you I'll give this a try!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I have updated the input to answer your question I think.